# How to pass string argument to numba njit python function from inside another whilst specifying signature type?

Tags: python, jit, numba

numba 0.51.2

I'm trying to pass a string argument to a njit function inside another njit function. For example:

```
import numba as nb    
from numba import njit, types

@njit(nb.void(types.unicode_type))
def bar(string):
    pass

@njit(nb.void(types.unicode_type))
def foo1(string):
    bar(string)

@njit(nb.void(types.unicode_type))
def foo2(string):
    bar("Testing")
```

I can call `foo1("Test")` fine, however, `foo2("Test")` fails with error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function bar at 0x00000258625F0678>)) with parameters (Literal[str](Testing))
Known signatures:
 * (unicode_type,) -> none
 * parameterized
[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function bar at 0x00000258625F0678>))
[2] During: typing of call at <ipython-input-4-62a1e466b1c1> (14)


File "<ipython-input-4-62a1e466b1c1>", line 14:
def foo2(string):
    bar("Testing")
    ^
```

I don't have any issues running either function when I try and run the njit function without specifying the signature, however, I intend to use the `numba.pycc` ahead-of-time compiler which, as far as I'm aware, requires the signatures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit - As a work around I've been able to pass the string through by creating a `typed.List` with signature `types.ListType(types.unicode_type)` and indexing the first element. Is there a better way?

Comment: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6907